# C++: seeding random number generator outside of main()

Tags: c++, random

I was creating a simple program that simulates a coin toss for my class.  (Actually, class is over this term and i'm just working through the rest of the projects that weren't required).  It involves the creating and calling a function that generates a random number between 1 and 2.  Originally, I tried to seed the random number generator within the function that would be using it (coinToss); however, it did not produce a random number.  Each time the program was run it was the same number as though I had only used

`rand()`

instead of

```
unsigned seed = time(0);
srand(seed);
rand();
```

Yet, when i moved the above within

```
int main()
```

it worked fine.

My question is 1)why did it not work when setup within the function that called it and (2) how does `rand()`
have access to what was done by `srand()` if they do not both occur in the same function?
Obviously, i'm a beginner so please forgive me if i didn't formulate the question correctly.  Also, my book has only briefly touched on `rand()` and `srand()` so that's all i really know.
thanks for any help!

Pertinent code:

First attempt that didn't work:

```
int main()
{  
    //...........
    coinToss();
    //...........
 }

 int coinToss()
 {
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    return 1 + rand() % 2;
  }
```

Second attempt which did work:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    coinToss();
 }

 int coinToss()
 { 
    return 1 + rand() % 2;
  }
```

Comment: By doing %2 you are really only checking the randomness of bit 0 of the number (witch has been shown to be not that random in rand() case). I once suggested (on SO) doing integer division. ie rand()/ (RAND_MAX/2) but somebody pointed out that was just checking bit 31 of the number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably only want to seed the random number generator once. `rand()` returns the next pseudo-random number from it's internal generator. Every time you call `rand()` you will get the next number from the internal generator.

`srand()` however sets the initial conditions of the random number generator. You can think of it as setting the 'starting-out point' for the internal random number generator (in reality it's a lot more complicated than that, but it's a useful cognitive model to follow).

So, you should be calling `srand(time(0))` exactly once in your application - somewhere near the beginning. After that, you can call `rand()` as many times as you want!

**However**

To answer your actual question - the first version doesn't work because `time()` returns the number of seconds since the *epoch*. So If you call `coinToss()` several times in a second (say, if you wanted to simulate 100 coin tosses), then you'd be constantly seeding the random number generator with the same number, thereby resetting it's internal state (and thus the next number you get) every time.

Anyway - using `time()` as a seed to `srand()` is somewhat crappy for this very reason - `time()` doesn't chage very often, and worse, it's *predictable*. If you know the current time, you can work out what `rand()` will return. The internet has many, many examples of better `srand()` seeds.

Comment: I would imagine that multiple calls to `srand(time(0))` might still be OK if they were separated by enough time (which might be hard to guarantee, so maybe best to only call it once at the begining)...

Comment: thanks! so, was it generating the same answer because `unsigned seed = time(0)` keys `seed` to the system clock and the program takes less than a second to run so `unsigned seed = time(0)` will pull the same value each time it's called since `time(0)` is based on seconds?

Comment: @knobcreekman: Not sure... you might be able to test that by adding a `sleep()` of 2-5 seconds between calls to the function.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner "might" being the operative word. It's entirely possible that giving srand monotonically increasing values every time you were about to call rand would still screw up the "randomness".

Comment: @Frustrated... Well, there really is no need at all to call srand() multiple times, with the possible exception of the application gaining access to a better seed value or a better generator later on in execution. However, since we're talking about what is essentially homework, and not cryptography, I think we can leave it at that. :)

Comment: I like time() as you know you will not get the same seed value for the next 32 years so each run of your program will have a unique sequence of random numbers. If you run the application more than once a second (generally not the case you can start using Milli-seconds but that reduces the time between repeated seeds). Though as you say this can be predicted so is not good to use for cryptography, **BUT** other problems with rand() make it unsuitable for cryptography so the point is moot. Summary: For all normal uses of rand() time(0) is a perfectly good seed.

Comment: @Thomi: Actually calling seed more than once in a program reduces randomness as it decreases the implied entropy. You should never re-seed (unless you want to get the same set of randoms again (like in unit-testing)).

Comment: If your application is designed to run multiple instance per second but only for a short burst (ie 1000 runs then its done). Pass an counter as the first argument to the application and append that: ie `srand(time(0) + lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]));`

Comment: @thomi... thanks for the edit to the question. I see i have a lot to learn about random numbers ... and everything else to do with programming :-)

Comment: @Martin York: The prng used for rand() is only required to have at least 16 bits of state. So even though you won't get the same seed value for the next 32 years, you might exhaust all the initial prng states in as little as ~18 days.

Comment: @Chris Hopman: Not according to this page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/srand.html

Comment: @Martin York: that's POSIX. The link states that there is no conflict with ISO C, which is correct: POSIX's requirement for 32+ bits of state does not conflict with ISO C's requirement for 16+ bits of state.

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo-random number generators (like `rand`) work by taking a single starting number (the seed) and performing a numeric transformation on it each time you request a new number. You want to seed the generator just once, or it will continually get reset, which is not what you want.

As you discovered, you should just call `srand` just once in `main`. Also note that a number of `rand` implementations have pretty short cycles on the low 4 bits or so. In practice this means you might get an easily predictable repeating cycle of numbers You might want to shift the return from `rand` right by 4-8 bits before you take the `% 2`.

EDIT: The call would look something like:
`return 1 + (rand() >> 6) % 2;`

Comment: thanks for the info.  I'm not sure what the last part means about shifting bits though, i think that's more advanced than me

Comment: @knobcreekman I edited my answer to show what the code would look like. Newer `rand` implementations don't have that flaw though.

Answer (score 1):

Seed *only once* per program, not every time you call `coinToss()`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Mark B's answer: It is not so much that the random number generator is reset as it sets a new variable to be used in calculating random numbers.  However your program doesn't do that much work between calls to srand.  Therefore every time you call srand(time(0)) it is using the same seed, so you are resetting the internal state of the random number generator .  If you put a sleep in there so that time(0) changed you would not get the same number every time.

As for how data passes from srand to rand, it is fairly simple, a global variable is used.  All names that start with an underscore and a capital letter or two underscores are reserved for variables used by your compiler. More than likely this variable has been declared static so it isn't visible outside of the translation unit(aka the library file that contains your compiler's standard library.)  This is done so that #define STUFF 5 doesn't break your standard library.

Answer (score 0):

for simple simulations, you must not change the seed at all during the simulation. Your simulation will be "worse" in that case.

To understand this, you should see pseudo random sequences as a big wheel of fortune. When you change the seed, it is like you change the position, and then, each call to rand will give you a *different* number. If you roll again, it will be more probable finding yourself repeating numbers.